# Cant remove page from url pagination to prevent error

Tags: php, cakephp

I keep getting a page out of range error.

The problem only happens when I am page:2 or above and I perform a search.
The search works fine unless this is only 1 page found and then I get the error if the URL has page 2 or above.

I tried resetting the page no, to 1 and I tried a try/catch block without any success, from previous posts.

How can I perform a search and reset the page:x back to page1 so I dont get this error?  I couldnt find this answer in the docs or google.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#PaginatorHelper

Error: The requested address '../admin_list2/page:2' was not found on this server.

```
in controller 


  $this->Paginator->settings = array(
                      'conditions'=> array ($tutor=>$tutorId,$conditionStartDate=>$valStartdate, 
                          $conditionEndDate=>$valEnddate, $conditionInvoice=>$invoice),
                       'order' => array('TimeSheet.period_start_date'=>'desc'),   
                       'limit' => $noRecords,
                'page' => 1,
                       'recursive'=>-1);  



            $timesheet= $this->Paginator->paginate('TimeSheet');



try {
        $this->Paginator->paginate();
    } catch (NotFoundException $e) {
        //Do something here like redirecting to first or last page.

        debug('error'); // never works
    }

http://....list2/page:2
```

Comment: Your  controller method is admin_list2 ? How you distribute queries with search terms beetwen pages ?

Comment: I am using a post method? is this what you mean and I need to use Get?

Comment: You can store post variables in session and then use again or use GET method.

Answer (score 0):

Saline is correct You can store post variables in session and then use again or use GET method. –  Salines 1 hour ago

This tutorial explains how it is done.

http://www.pabloleanomartinet.com/cakephp-2-x-filter-basic-search-example/